# How to track changes made to View of Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to track the changes made to View of list in sharepoint 2007. Some random user made changes to the list view by simply using Modify this view button. Could it be tracked like the user name and date.

Answer (score 1):

You can track changes made to the view from the [SPChangeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spchangeview%28v=office.12%29.aspx) class.

Find out how to use the SPChange API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447511(v=office.14).aspx

How to create a query to look for specific changes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447550(v=office.14).aspx

The links are for SP2010 but they will work for 2007 too.